# Return list of query in Java 1 dimensional e.g., 1 row is returned

Tags: java, mysql, iteration

I am having a lot of trouble iterating through all my records. Perhaps, by reading my code someone could help.

```
private String saveData(Handle handle, String username, String name, String prof, String table) {
    String sqlCommand;

    Map<String, Object> userResults;

    for (Integer tableNum = 1; tableNum < 5; tableNum++) {

        //query all tables
        sqlCommand = String.format("SELECT varname FROM s" + tableNum.toString());
        userResults = handle.createQuery(sqlCommand)
                .bind("username", username)
                .first();

        //attempt to ierate all records
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : userResults.entrySet()) {
            Object obj = entry.getValue(); // doesnt have .get(string) as below
        }

        //get the desired field
        logger.debug("Results: " + userResults.toString());
        String varname = (String) userResults.get("varname");
        if ((varname.toLowerCase()).matches(name.toLowerCase())) 
            return "";
    }

    //save data
    return name;
}
```

How do I iterate through each record of the table?

Comment: That is not the standard way to query databases in Java, so at a minimum you should explain what `Handle` is and how it works.

Comment: What is the standard way to query a database in Java?

Comment: Using JDBC (or by a higher level framework like JPA).

Answer (score 0):

You say this works for row1. You cannot go to the next row as there is `.first();` in your handle and you have not tried to fetch next record. Modify your query - the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html) says you can use `.list(maxRows);`

Comment: No. The correctly typed property of handle to use is .list(maxRows); Not .getResultList().